# select tag value not reflect change in v-model

Tags: vue.js, laravel-blade

v-model on  tag doesnt not reflect any changes in the blade template.

I have tried this with an empty html file but its working, but only got the problem in blade template

//blade

```
<div id="fruit-container">
<select  v-model="fruit">
    <option disabled value="">Choose a fruit</option> 
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Strawberry</option>
   </select>
 <span>Fruit chosen: @{{fruit}}</span>
</div>
```

//js

```
new Vue({
 el:'#fruit-container',
 data:{fruit:""}
})
```

the value `@{{fruit}}` never show up when i select the different option, and this is only not working in blade i am wondering what did i do wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your `data` to this:

```
data() {
  return { fruit: '' }
}
```

Comment: Here is an example in a sandbox. I know this doesn't work with laravel and blade, but it does show that your code should work. So I think there might be something wrong with the setup. https://codesandbox.io/s/zxr3v9mv74?fontsize=14